# I am not able to label the vertex of the following graph in mathematica, can some one please help me

Tags: graphs-and-networks

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 5 -> 6}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

> ```
> Graph::optx: Unknown option VertexLabeling in Graph[{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1->2,1->3,2->5,2->6,5->6},VertexLabeling->True].
> ```

```
GraphPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 
  5 -> 6}, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

> ```
> GraphPlot::argx: GraphPlot called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
> ```

This was the message came after trying to draw the graph.

Comment: VertexLabeling works with GraphPlot, but not with Graph. GraphPlot only expects one argument. If you drop the $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then the GraphPlot command works.

Comment: But that will give only the dots right, I need  a graph with edges as well as isolated vertices also.

Comment: GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 5 -> 6}, VertexLabeling -> True]  gives dots and edges.

Answer (score 1):

Seems in Mathematica 10 you should use the `VertexLabels` option. So, your code can be written like this:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 5 -> 6}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Which will give the result shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate some ways to motivate play:

```
{v, e} = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 
    5 -> 6}};
GraphPlot[e, VertexLabeling -> All]
Graph[v, e, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexStyle -> LightBlue, VertexSize -> 0.6]
GraphPlot[e, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[Style[#2, Red], Background -> White], #1] &)]
```

[image]